# slds control lightning:select required asterisk and element alignment

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

I have a `lightning:select` component that is required, which adds an asterisk above the input:

```
            <td role="gridcell">
              <div class="form-group">
                <lightning:select aura:id="deliveryMethodPicklist" value="{!v.selectedDeliveryMethodValue}" onchange="{!c.handleDeliveryMethodChange}" name="deliveryMethodPicklist" required="true">
                  <option value="">--None--</option>
                  <aura:iteration items="{!v.deliveryMethodMap}" var="option">
                      <option text="{!option.value}" value="{!option.key}" selected="{!option.selected}" />
                  </aura:iteration>   
                </lightning:select>
              </div>
            </td>
```

The asterisk displays above select input. Is there a way to either re-position or remove it without removing other required asterisks on the component. If I set css on `slds-required` then all asterisks are removed. I want to keep the select required, but just need to adjust the placement of the asterisk or simply remove it and the required field will still work. Finally, is there a way to vertically center the picklist within the table column? Currently, it sits flush to the bottom border of the cell and when the required message displays the picklist moves to the center and the message displays below it. Can it be centered vertically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add either custom data attribute like `data-select_no-asterics` or similar named CSS class and in overrides use it to be more specific on where you want to disable it

Don't know what standard classes are, but from you question I assume it'll be like this.

```
lightning:select.select_no_asterics .slds-required {
  display: none;
}
```

or `lightning:select[data-select_no_asterics]`